# How can we correctly identify the mass term for an arbitrary lagrangian?

Tags: mass, field-theory

For example, in the invariant lagrangian $U(1)$, the mass term associated to the $A_\mu$ field is the leading term for $A_\mu A^\mu$. On the other side, for complex scalar fields the mass term is the leading term for $\phi^\dagger\phi$.

Let's suppose we encounter a new structure in nature, say a new field, which now transforms under a certain symmetry. How can one identify the mass term for said lagrangian?

Comment: One way I know is to find the dispersion relation from the equations of motion, that tells you how the energy behaves as p goes to zero. If E=p (that is, if E goes to zero) it is massless, if E^2=p^2+m^2, the term with the m is the mass term.

Comment: I don't think it's a stretch to say that "the mass term is the one that is quadratic in the field."  But this really just comes back to @PatoGalmarini's answer, because the one that's quadratic in the field is the dominant contribution to the dispersion at zero momentum.

Comment: "said lagrangian" - I don't think the lagrangian by itself is enough to say. The standard model lagrangian only has quadratic field terms (without derivatives) for the Higgs - and in the usual picture that quadratic term represents a negative mass-squared. All the other mass terms are due to the vev of the Higgs - i.e., you have to know what the vacuum state of the fields is before you know what the masses are.

Comment: @Rokas there is no quadratic term in the Dirac Lagrangian

Comment: @infinitezero, sure there is: $m\bar\psi\psi$. Quadratic in the field, not the mass.

Comment: @Foster oh they did say in the field. Sorry, too early to read